# Getting error while access the struct type of array element as undefined (type []ParentIDInfo has no field or method PCOrderID)

Tags: go, struct, slice

I am new to golang and I have one issue which I think community can help me to solve it.

I have one data structure like below

```
     type ParentIDInfo struct {
    PCOrderID      string         `json:"PCorderId",omitempty"`
    TableVarieties TableVarietyDC `json:"tableVariety",omitempty"`
    ProduceID      string         `json:"PRID",omitempty"`
}

type PCDCOrderAsset struct {
    PcID         string              `json:"PCID",omitempty"`
    DcID         string              `json:"DCID",omitempty"`
    RequiredDate string              `json:"requiredDate",omitempty"`
    Qty          uint64              `json:"QTY",omitempty"`
    OrderID      string              `json:"ORDERID",omitempty"`
    Status       string              `json:"STATUS",omitempty"`
    Produce      string              `json:"Produce",omitempty"`
    Variety      string              `json:"VARIETY",omitempty"`
    Transports   []TransportaionPCDC `json:"Transportaion",omitempty"`
    ParentInfo   []ParentIDInfo        `json:"ParentInfo",omitempty"`
```

So I have issue to access the **PCOrderID** which inside the **[]ParentIDInfo** . I have tried below however I getting error as "pcdcorder.ParentInfo.PCOrderID undefined (type []ParentIDInfo has no field or method PCOrderID)"

```
keyfarmercas = append(keyfarmercas, pcdcorder.ParentInfo.PCOrderID)
```

Any help will be very good

Thanks in advance

Comment: `PCDCOrderAsset.ParentInfo` is not a struct, it does not have a `PCOrderID` field. It's a slice, its elements do, e.g. `pcdcorder.ParentInfo[0].PCOrderID`. Whether this is what you want we can't tell.

Comment: Thanks@icza I think you right its slice, sorry I am new to it so I thought like that, could you please make it answer of this query. Its resolve my issue. thanks a lot I tried same way but I didn't provide ParentInfo[0] I used as ParentInfo[ ].

Comment: sorry I am new to go so I didn't understand the slice one why should I got -1. no logic to give it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PCDCOrderAsset.ParentInfo` is not a struct, it does not have a `PCOrderID` field. It's a slice (of element type `ParentIDInfo`), so its elements do, e.g. `pcdcorder.ParentInfo[0].PCOrderID`.

Whether this is what you want we can't tell. `pcdcorder.ParentInfo[0].PCOrderID` gives you the `PCOrderID` field of the first element of the slice. Based on your question this may or may not be what you want. You may want to append all IDs (one from each element). Also note that if the slice is empty (its length is 0), then `pcdcorder.ParentInfo[0]` would result in a runtime panic. You could avoid that by first checking its length and only index it if its not empty.

In case you'd want to add ids of all elements, you could use a `for` loop to do that, e.g.:

```
for i := range pcdorder.ParentInfo {
    keyfarmercas = append(keyfarmercas, pcdcorder.ParentInfo[i].PCOrderID)
}
```